# Adding validation to <p> element in React

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to render a `<p>` element whose value is dependent on a state variable. I want to apply validation to the contents of that element.How to do that?

Ex: `<p> {Number(this.state.projectPrice).toFixed(2)}</p>`

I want to apply validation if project price is less than 5,it show show error message and submit button is disabled.

Comment: Paste your full component code here with JSX

Answer (score 0):

I guess your component is a controlled component. In that case, in the handle function, you can add a validator. For example:

```
handleChange(event) {
    // in the if, you can set an error message and choose not to update the value
    if(event.target.value > 5){ this.setState({error:"value greater than 5"});
    // if number is less than 5 only update
    else {this.setState({value: event.target.value});}
}
```

...

also in the submit function also you can check if there is any value as above, so you can't press the submit button, if value greater than 5 or if there is no value

=========

Based on the comment :

You can write a function that goes something like this

```
validator = () => {
 if(Number(this.state.projectPrice) < 5){
  return Number(this.state.projectPrice).toFixed(2)
 } else {
  return "error"
 }
}
```

and in the return statement `<p>{this.validator()}</p>`

Comment: Where do I associate the event? My element is like <p>{Number (this.state.projectPrice).toFixed(2)}</p>